# double authentication issue on IIS / Report Server (SQL server 2008)

Tags: iis, sql-server-2008, reportserver

On a 2003 server box, with SQL server 2008 installed (ReportServer deployed in IIS mode), I've got a virtual directory within IIS with it's security set to 'windows authentication', with the following html code:

```
<body>
<h1>test</h1>
<iframe src="/reportserver" witdh="50%" height="50%" />
</body>
```

From the outside, I've got a first login/pwd box displayed to access the html code, then a *second* one to display the content of the iframe.

On the same type of server, but with SQL Server 2005, I don't have this issue (i.e. only one login box).

My thought is that the first token should give acces to both the page and the iframe, isn't it?

Any hints on how to setup the reportserver to fix this?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently had a similar issue. Turned out that Reporting Services for 2008 was installing with SSL enabled by default and I was getting forced redirections to https://localhost/ReportServer. Just mentioning it because it caught me by surprise...

I disabled SSL redirects by setting the SecureConnectionLevel = 0 in the RSReportServer.config file.

Comment: interesting, and how did you detect this redirection?
And how did you disable SSL on reportServer?

Comment: try going to http://machinename/reportserver/ if your address bar changes to https://machinename/reportserver/ then there is some redirection going on.

Comment: no redirection there, but I'll digg into the <authenticationtypes> section of my SSRS config file... thanks for the hint

Comment: Found the issue, my AuthenticationTypes section was only listing RSWindowsNTLM. I added RSWindowsNegotiate and it solved my issue. I'll give you the answer.